# Loop for all files with certain name in directory in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a script that would test whether my file is exactly as it should be, but I haven't been using bash before:

```
 #!/bin/bash
./myfile <test.in 1>>test.out 2>>testerror.out
if cmp -s "test.out" "pattern.out"
    then
        echo "Test matches pattern"
    else
        echo "Test does not match pattern"
    fi
if cmp -s "testerror.out" "pattern.err"
    then
        echo "Errors matches pattern"
    else
        echo "Errors does not match pattern"
    fi
```

Can I write it in such way that after calling ./script.sh myfile pattern my scripts would run over all files named pattern*.in and check if myfile gives same files as pattern*.out and pattern*.err ? e.g there are files pattern1, pattern2, pattern4 and i want to run test for them, but not for pattern3 that doesn't exist.

Can I somehow go around creating new files? (Assuming i don't need them) If I were doing it from command line, I'd go with something like

```
< pattern.in ./myfile | diff -s ./pattern.out
```

but I have no idea how to write it in script file to make it work.

Or maybe i should just use rm everytime?

Comment: Use a `for` loop to iterate over all the files that match the pattern.

Comment: `for file in pattern*.in`

Comment: You can use variables like `< "$file" ./myfile`

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49456684/edit) to include more information.  Do you mean you want to be able to provide `myfile` and `pattern` as command-line parameters to `script.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```
for infile in pattern*.in ; do  
    outfile="${infile%.in}.out"
    errfile="${infile%.in}.err"

    echo "Working on input $infile with output $outfile and error $errfile"
    ./myfile <"$infile" >>"$outfile" 2>>"$errfile"
    # Your `if`..`fi` blocks here, referencing infile/outfile/errfile
done
```

The `%` replacement operator strips a substring off the end of a variable's value.  So if `$infile` is `pattern.in`, `${infile%.in}` is that without the trailing `.in`, i.e., `pattern`.  The `outfile` and `errfile` assignments use this to copy the first part (e.g., `pattern1`) of the particular `.in` file being processed.